# Unable to add text

Tags: text-object

Im a newbie trying to "Add Text" but I cannot seem to find the Text option under shift A.

I tried searching up in search bar and no luck with that either.
No one else seems to have the same problem, sorry for the dumb question and thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: based on your screen shot you are currently in edit mode for an existing mesh object. tab to object mode.

Comment: thank you so much!!